# Return 1 - Popularity Contest

Tags: popularity-contest

**The Task**

Create a function/subroutine which returns 1. You can make it as elaborate as you like, as long as it returns 1.

**The Rules**

The entry with the most upvote wins - just like any popularity contest. Good luck!

Comment: +1 four downvotes but 13 Answers?, if people are having fun with this question why so many downvotes?

Comment: 13 answers, but only two of them have garnered any votes. Perhaps this is our version of the emacs vs vi question -- one where everyone has an answer but none of them are particularly better than another.

Comment: @anakata, because four (make that six now) people think that this is the kind of question they think would have been better not posted. Some people are against [tag:popularity-contest] on principle, and this is scraping the bottom of that category.

Comment: This is one of those places where codegolf fits uneasily into the stackexchange format. Compare the [Collatz Conjecture](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture), which is also trending right now. The answers are all pretty mundane (no offense), because it's not a good problem for creative golfing — the naive approach is also the shortest. Whereas in this question, the popularity-contest allows all kinds of interesting answers to a very trivial task. Far more enjoyable to read — but stackexchange is supposed to avoid open-ended stuff like this. Thus the downvotes.

Comment: @breadbox Point taken - I will make my challenges more interesting from now `:)`

Comment: in sql-server `print '1'`

Comment: @breadbox You could say this question is the Rube-Goldberg of all questions... ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most creative way to display 42](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/most-creative-way-to-display-42)

Answer (score 37):

**Golf Script**

```
1
```

It took a long time to optimise this code to its most pure, and dare I say it - beautiful form. Such elegance of the language does not come without years of dedicated practice. The program that, without a Zero-Instruction-Set-Computer can literally never be compressed any further. My entire code golf career has been leading to this moment.

I am free. I am alive.

I see the code that underlies the universe.

Comment: Can you write a program that only uses a single bit?

Comment: @Kevin Only in Minecraft (I've done it before - made a 3x5 px screen and everything).

Comment: `without a Zero-Instruction-Set-Computer can literally never be compressed any further`. Our current computers can easily handle 0 instructions programs. All you need a language that has: "The empty program returns 1" in its specification

Answer (score 36):

### C

Two examples, using obscure language features such as “strong return” (`return!`) and the “approaches” operator (`-->`):

```c
int foo(void) {
    return! 0;
}
```

```c
int bar(void) {
    int i=7;
    while (i --> 0);
    return-i;
}
```

Comment: And the special `return-i` keyword :P

Comment: For those who want to learn more on '-->' see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Answer (score 33):

## Brainfuck

```
+++++++
+++++++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
++++++++++
++++++++++.
```

Or if you are not fun at parties:

```
+++++++[->+++++++<]>.
```

Comment: That looks more like a lowercase `l` than a `1`.

Answer (score 26):

### APL

```
one ← {⍴⍴⍴⍵}
```

`⍴` gives you the dimensions of a vector. The dimension of that is always one-dimensional, so the dimension of *that* is always one. Or:

"Rho, rho, rho of X
Always equals one,
Rho is dimension; rho rho, rank
APL is fun!"

(I didn't write that verse, it's Stallman's.)

Comment: I have learned the Modern Major Generals Song, sung the Money song by Monty Python and Still Alive from Portal... and that is still the nerdiest song that has _ever_ been stuck in my head.

Good find marinus! A good verse Stallman!

Comment: The same thing in J: `# @: # @: #` (Spaces are optional)

Answer (score 21):

### Java

```
public static int funWithOne() {
    try {
        try {
            return funWithOne();
        } finally {
            return funWithOne();
        }
    } catch (Throwable _) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This will call itself 2<sup>1024</sup> times (this number may vary on different platforms) before finally returning `1`. Don't hold your breath, though; it will easily take *much* longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: "This will call itself 2^1024 times" Why? I think its a stack issue. Try to call yourself until you run out of stack, then do it again, and again?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr there's some try finally stuff here that keeps the stack low, but still has a lot of calls

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438786/try-finally-block-prevents-stackoverflowerror).

Answer (score 19):

### Unix Shell (Bourne, POSIX, bash, ksh, csh, …)

```
expr 0
```

This *prints* 0 but *returns* 1, which may come as a surprise to programmers used to other languages. You can turn off the printed output and see the return code by running `expr 0 >/dev/null; echo $?`.

Comment: I've been bit by this before.  You want to know if a process exists?  `$(pidof progname) < 1`

Answer (score 19):

**Fish**

x sends the program counter in a random direction. # is a wall that the program counter "bounces" off. This will literally wander around aimlessly until it finds the "^" and then print 1 and finish.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx###xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx#;#xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx#n#xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx#1#xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx#^#xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: +1 for both tiring the interpreter and letting other ><> pee in their pants. Lol.

Comment: It's nice how this is easily translated into Befunge 98; simply change every `x` into a `?`, every `#` into a `r`, `n` into `.` and `;` into `@`. However, this ><> program looks better than the equivalent Befunge. Translation shown here: http://ideone.com/ZyuSKk

Comment: Maybe I like this too much; here is another Befunge, but this one takes ~4 million operations to finish. I imagine that it can be directly translated into ><> by changing every `?` into a `x` and every `#` into a `!` (should work fine when left the same too) and (of course) `.` to `n` and `@` to `;`. http://ideone.com/gfApjT

Comment: @Quincunx looks like it should take about 2^10 tries, with an expected number of operation per try at about 10. This gives me about 2000 operations. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Quincunx Nevermind, it's 4^10. Got it. lol. FYI, I'm pretty sure that code can be minimized greatly and still do the same thing.

Answer (score 18):

## Java

This is one of my favorite Java specific question.

```java
public static int ret1() {
    try {
        return 0;
    } finally {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: Trying to return in a `try` block instantly fires `finally` which returns 1 before the other `return` statement can run.

Comment: Returning in a finally block should throw a compile error. I can't think of any legitimate use case for doing it.

Comment: In C# it does throw compile error, but in Java it is possible. Of course it doesn't mean it's useful, neither can I think of any legitimate use case

Answer (score 16):

### JavaScript

```
// we all know that OOP == good
function OneManager() {
    // constants == good too
    this.values = {
        ERROR: -1, // value on error
        ONE: 1 // desired value
    }
    this.value = this.values.ERROR // set the value to ERROR
    this.setValue = function(num) {
        if (typeof num !== "number") throw new Error('cannot set value to non-number')
        if (!this.value) this.value = this.values.ERROR // oh noes
        else this.value = num
    }
}
// initialize the one
OneManager.prototype.initializeOne = function() {
    this.setValue(this.values.ONE) // set the value to ONE
    return true // return true for success
}
// get the value
OneManager.prototype.getValue = function() {
    if (this.value == this.values.ERROR) { // if the value is ERROR
        throw new Error('value not initialized')
    } else return this.value // return the value
}

function getOne() {
    var m = new OneManager() // make a OneManager
    var success = m.initializeOne() // initialize the value
    if (success) return m.getValue() // return the value
    else  {
        // there was an error in the initialization
        var retVal = m.values.ERROR // we will return an error
        delete m // maybe it's corrupted
        return retVal // return an error
    }
}

alert(getOne())
```

Comment: That's one robust piece of code you got here.

Comment: @Kwaio I lost it reading your comment

Comment: `OO == good` or `OO === good`?

Comment: @JoshWillik: Yes. ;-)

Answer (score 16):

### JavaScript

```
function getOne() {
    return -~![];
}
```

Explanation:

- first `![]` evaluates to `false`.
- then `~false` becomes `-1` because `false` is first casted to `0`, and `~0 == -1`.
- finally, `--1` evaluates to `1`.

Alternate:

```
return +!([][~~{}])
```

Crazy alternate (each line is exactly 80 chars long):

```
this[693741..toString(36)]('acnuftiao nobcbdaterbaurn +abeba!!be'.replace(/b./g,
function(b){return '{}()'.split('')['aecd'.split('').indexOf(b.charAt(1))]})[''+
'replace'](new RegExp('a'+Array(5).join('(.)'),'g'),(a='$')+'4321'.split([]+[]).
join(a)))
```

Comment: -~{}+[] is another approach.  {}+[] evaluates to 0.

Answer (score 12):

### Haskell & The Church of the ADT

```
data One = One deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum, Show, Read)
```

This defines the **one** true `One`. This `One` is both the type denoting *Oneness*, and the constructor `One`, which is itself the nullary function that returns the **one** true, and only one value of type `One`, which is, behold, `One`.

Usage in the `ghci` REPL:

```
λ: One                  -- One returns the one true One
One
λ: One == One           -- One is equal to itself, as no others are 
True
λ: One < One            -- One is no less than itself
False
λ: minBound :: One      -- One is the least One there is, yet it is all you need
One
λ: maxBound :: One      -- One is as big as the universe of One, it is omnipotent
One
λ: [ One .. One ]       -- One is the beginning, and ending, of all that is One
[One]
λ: show One             -- The textual gospel of One
"One"
λ: read "One" :: One    -- To read the word of One, is to become one with One
One
```

The full [Book of One](https://bitbucket.org/mtnviewmark/haskell-playground/src/789e66e13736f5f5ad6ca09cceef7d20d4c7beca/golf/12141-One.hs?at=default) is now on-line. Loading it gets you both testaments: Computation and Arithmetic. This enables you to explore more truths:

```
λ: One + One            -- One can only add to its magnificence
One
λ: negate One
*** Exception: One cannot be negated, mortal fool!

λ: One `div` One        -- One is indivisible
One
λ: One `mod` One
*** Exception: Nothing can modulate the power of One

λ: toRational One       -- Ye shall know One as both Numerator and Denominator
1 % 1
λ: toInteger One * 42   -- One multiplies all to wholeness
42
λ: toRational One / 2   -- Even divided, One is on top
1 % 2
```

Answer (score 8):

### Perl

```
sub ret1 { print $->$= }
```

(Despite appearances, the function doesn't print anything.)

I know Perl programmers like to say TMTOWTDI, but this is a task for which T *really* MTOWTDI.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP

```
<?php
function getOne() {
  return 0 + "one" == 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you prefer a longer one, here's an alternative (it doesn't print anything):

```
<?php
function getOne() {
    return print('the' + 'integer' + 'between' + 0 and 2);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### C

```c
float one(void)
{
    const int n = 24; // magic number
    float x = 0.5f;
    float y = x;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        x *= 0.5f;
        y += x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: It's the geometric series 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 1.

Comment: and it loops 24 times because float has 24 bits of precision

Answer (score 8):

## Groovy

```
-"""
int getRandomNumber()
{
    return 4;   //chosen by fair dice roll.
                //guaranteed to be random.
}
""".indexOf(4)
```

Doesn't contain 4

Comment: I think i've seen this on xkcd.

Comment: Yes, that was the idea :)

Answer (score 7):

## Rhetorical Java

You didn't say it had to be an integer 1.

```
float one_F(){
    return FloatFactoryFactory.getInstance(FloatFactoryFactory.
    defaultInstanceDescriptionString).getFactory(Locale.getLocale
    ("en-US")).createBuilder().setString("1.0").getResult();
}
```

Source: http://bash.org/?946461

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ECMAScript really)

```
function one() { return Number.length; }
```

Time for some spec porn.

Section [15.7.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3) states that the `length` property of the `Number` constructor is `1` (and we know that a constructor is a function object as mentioned in [4.3.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.4)), and that's because section [15.3.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.1) says:

> The value of the length property is an integer that indicates the “typical” number of arguments expected by the function. However, the language permits the function to be invoked with some other number of arguments.

…and since the `Number` constructor's typical number of arguments is 1, the `length` of `Number` is `1`. So one could say that the length of a number in Javascript is 1.

Answer (score 6):

### Tcl

```
proc return1 {} {
    catch {(5+2-3)/4}
}
```

Does not work as you might think.

`(5+2-3)/4` is not a valid command, so it throws an error (`return -code 1`), catch returns this number.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl

```
sub one{ $a[@a{@a[%a=map{@$a[@a{$a++=>$a}]+++$#$a+$a=>$a}$a]++}+$a] }
```

Open wide and say `aaaaa`.

The creative concept was to nest braces inside brackets inside braces... as deeply as possible, while still returning the desired result, and only using a "one" variable (`$a`, `@a`, `%a`, `@$a` and `$#$a` are of course all different variables).

Although this does modify its environment significantly, it will always return `1` on subsequent calls. To get a grasp of what it's doing, you might consider running this code:

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
for (1..8) {
  one();
  dump(@a);
  dump(%a);
  dump(@$a);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### MATHEMATICA

In my opinion, the most elegant mathematical way to return 1 using Mathematica:

```
-Exp[I Pi]
```

The Euler Identity.

Answer (score 5):

### Java

```
public class print {
    public static char getNum() throws Exception{
        String method = print.class.getSimpleName()+Splitter.class.getDeclaredMethods().length;
        return (char)Splitter.class.getMethod(method).invoke(null);
    }
}
class Splitter{
    public static char print1(){
        return P.getNum();
    }
}
class P{
    public static char getNum(){
        String s = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[P.class.getDeclaredMethods().length].getMethodName();
        return s.charAt(s.length()-P.class.getSimpleName().length());
    }
    public void doNothing(){}
}
```

Can be adjusted to return any other positive number `n` by adding the methods `printX` for `X` from 1 to n into Splitter. For example, modifying `Splitter` to

```
class Splitter{
    public static char print1(){
        return P.getNum();
    }
    public static char print2(){
        return P.getNum();
    }
}
```

Will return '2', without any other changes necessary. The added methods should, apart from the name, be an exact duplicate of `print1`.
Uses reflection to get the number of methods in splitter, and call a function with that name. `P.getNum`, which is then called, reads the stack trace and parses out the last character in the calling method, and displays it.

Calling `print.getNum()` return the character '1'

Edit - modified to use no String/integer/etc literals.

Answer (score 5):

**C#**

It should depend on hardware architecture:

```
return IntPtr.Size / (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? 8 : 4);
```

WOW!

Answer (score 5):

#### Javascript 8 bytes

is this simple enough?

```
(+!~~{})
```

Comment: Returns can only be used in a function. Just saying.

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ fixed ;D

Answer (score 5):

### C#

Merging this (controversial) one with the neighboring (controversial) [Collatz Conjecture](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture):

```cs
public int CollatzOne()
{
    var current = new BigInteger(new Random().Next(1, Int32.MaxValue));
    var history = new[] { new BigInteger(-1), new BigInteger(-1), new BigInteger(-1) };
    do
    {
        history[0] = history[1];
        history[1] = history[2];
        history[2] = current;
        if (current.IsEven)
            current /= 2;
        else
            current = current * 3 + 1;
    } while (current != history[0]);
    return (int)history.Min();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

Abusing the RNG...

```
Random.new(56417).rand(10000)
```

Generates a "random" number between 0 and 10000, and because I picked the right seed it just so happens to be 1. ;)

Script I used to find the number:

```
irb(main):001:0> (1..100000).select{|x|Random.new(x).rand(10000) == 1}
=> [14033, 25845, 35101, 36955, 45334, 56417, 87438, 87460, 99178, 99451]
```

Answer (score 4):

## R

A classic:

```
TRUE + 0
```

`+`  tries to coerce its argument to a common type: here, because of the order of precedence, it coerces to integers. The coercion of `TRUE` to an integer gives 1.

Comment: Would `+TRUE` not work?

Comment: @Griffin  `+TRUE` happens to give `TRUE`.

Comment: Also `FALSE + 1`, am I correct?

Comment: @Timtech yes you are.

Answer (score 4):

### Turing Machine

Single-state Turing machine with B as the blank symbol, computes 1 (= 0.111... in base 2):

```
q B 1 R q
```

(This follows Turing's convention of starting with a blank tape, and prefixing '0.' to the generated infinite sequence.)

Answer (score 4):

## C

It even includes documentation on its parameters.

```
    int
  return_1
(x)     int
       x;{
      /*x
     can
    be:
  any
 val
ue.
***/ return
!x?1:x /x;}
```

Comment: But that's a 2!

Comment: So? It's fully documented!

Answer (score 3):

### Python

```
one = lambda zero = 0o11: zero > 1 and all(one(zero-1) for l in '1111111111') and 1 or one and zero or one()
```

`one()` will call itself 111,111,111 times, each time returning 1, before returning a final value of 1.

You can also specify the number of digits. For example, `one(3)` will return 1 only 111 times.

I might add an explanation later, but I really don't have time at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

### R

```
NA ^ 0
```

Any number to the power of `0` is `1`.

Answer (score 3):

### Deadfish

```
riot
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby

Or any other language:

```
def one (n=111111)
    i=1
    n.times { |j| i^=j+1 }
    return i
end
```

Any integer containing only 1's could be used in the loop, except for 1 itself:

```
[11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, 11111111, 111111111].each { |n| puts one n } # etc..
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java

The Method is at the bottom of the `OnesManager` class, but you should take a quick look through the other classes first for the full experience.

**`NotOneException` class**:

```java
public class NotOneException extends Exception
{
    public NotOneException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
        System.out.println("If there's not one exception, how many are there?");
    }
}
```

**`One` class**:

```java
import java.lang.Math;

import java.util.Random;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class One
{
    public int one;
    static boolean amIAwesome = true;
    static Random random = new Random();
    public One()
    {

    }

    One initializeOne()
    {
        if(random.nextInt(3) == 0)
        {
            return initializeOneOne();
        }
        else if(random.nextInt(2) == 0)
        {
            return initializeAOne();
        }
        else
        {
            return initializeASingleOne();
        }
    }

    One initializeOneOne()
    {
        String aOneInDisguise = "" + (int)((int)(Math.PI * Math.E / random.nextDouble()) * Math.pow(3, 3));
        int notYetOne;
        while(aOneInDisguise.length() > BigInteger.ONE.intValue())
        {
            notYetOne = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < aOneInDisguise.length(); i++)
            {
                notYetOne += Integer.parseInt(aOneInDisguise.substring(i, i + 1));
            }
            aOneInDisguise = "" + notYetOne;
        }
        one = Integer.parseInt(aOneInDisguise) / 9;
        return this;
    }

    One initializeAOne()
    {
        one = (BigDecimal.ONE.intValue() >> 1) ^ 1;
        return this;
    }

    One initializeASingleOne()
    {
        one = 1;
        return this;
    }

    int getOne() throws NotOneException
    {
        try
        {
            return random.nextInt(3) == 0 ? random.nextInt(2) == 0 ? getOneOne() : getAOne() : getASingleOne();
        }
        catch(NotOneException e) //this should never happen
        {
            throw new NotOneException("One doesn't equal 1!");
        }
    }

    int getOneOne() throws NotOneException
    {
        if(one << one == 2)
        {
            return one;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotOneException("One doesn't equal 1!");
        }
    }

    int getAOne()
    {
        assert ((1 << 1) >> 1) == one == amIAwesome != (false && (true == ((1 ^ 0) == one)));
        return one;
    }

    int getASingleOne()
    {
        if(new Character((char)(Integer.toString(one).charAt((char)Integer.parseInt("" + one) - 1))).equals('1'))
        {
            return one;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**`OnesManager` class**:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnesManager
{
    static One[] ones;
    static Scanner sc;
    static int choice;
    static One one;

    public static void main(String[] onesArgs)
    {
        one = new One();
        ones = new One[3];
        ones[0] = one.initializeOneOne();
        ones[1] = one.initializeAOne();
        ones[2] = one.initializeASingleOne();
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("which One do you want? (0, 1, or 2): ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("1");

        try
        {
            returnOne();
        }
        catch(NotOneException e)
        {
            System.out.println("whoops");
        }
    }

    static int returnOne()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If we were Golfing, I would lose so bad.

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
import random
def ret_one():
    i = random.randint(0, ~(-1<<31))
    if i & 1:
        i = i & (i - 1)
    i = ~i & (i + 1)
    return i
print ret_one()
```

This is using some [low-level bit hacks](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/).

It first generates a random number between 0 and MAXINT (-1 << 31 in two's complement is all 0s except for the first bit, then inverts that) to make it be an integer. Then, if the number is odd, it turns off the rightmost bit. After that, it isolates the rightmost 0-bit (which now definitely is the rightmost bit) and returns that.

Another solution:

```
def ret_one():
    c = 1 + 20.37j
    return int(c.real)
print ret_one()
```

This makes use of Python's built-in complex number support. The term `1 + 20.37j` creates a complex number with 1.0 as its real and 20.37 as its complex part. We then take the real part and turn it into an int.

Answer (score 2):

## C

Return that not no error has occured! ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    return !errno;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash

```
false
```

Yes, this returns 1. Check with

```
echo $? # 1
```

Why? Because 0 is the "sucess" return code, everything else is "not success".

Answer (score 2):

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>

void kill_user_processes(void) {
    kill(-1, 9);
}

// Not guaranteed to work.
void kernel_panic(void) {
    kill(1, 11);
    kill(1, 30);
    kill(1, 15);
    // Last resort
    kill(-1, 9);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (geteuid() != 0) {
        puts("It's strongly recommended that you run this program as root for extra "
             "functionality. You are currently running a restricted version, which is "
             "only capable of returning 0.");
        atexit(kill_user_processes);
        sleep(5);
        exit(0);
    } else {
        atexit(kernel_panic);
        sleep(5);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Non-alphanumeric JavaScript

`[][(__=''+!!(_=+[]))[_$=-~-~-~_]+($$=''+{})[$=-~_]+($_=''+!_)[$]+$_[_]][$$[-~($+_$)]+$$[$]+(''+$/_)[$]+__[_$]+$_[_]+$_[$]+$_[$+$]+$$[-~($+_$)]+$_[_]+$$[$]+$_[$]](__[$]+__[$+$]+$_[_$]+$_[$]+$_[_]+"("+$+")")()`

Explanation:

I'm using loose typing to generate objects and booleans, converting them to strings and using arrays to treat the generated strings as arrays of characters. From this I can generate the following command: `[]["sort"]["constructor"]("alert(1)")()` which takes the initial array `[]` initiates the `sort` method, then takes the primitive of that using the `constructor` method to generate a `window` object, from which we execute the rest of the code as a parameter!

Answer (score 1):

## Python

If it's not against the rules to submit more than one:

```
one = lambda: 1
```

or

```
def one():
    return sum(map(int, str((True is not False).denominator)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
def one(n):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a^b, xrange(2**n+~(17<<n)^-3))
```

Returns `1` for any `n` (`n` must be a non-negative integer).

Example:

```
>>> one(7)
1
>>> one(20)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

```
def absolute_euler
  (Math::E.to_c ** ( Math::PI * "i".to_c )).abs.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

Why not write what we want?

```
function to() { return 1; }

to(); // 1
```

Comment: You answered during the 11th hour of the 1st day of August, and at the time of this writing have 1 upvote, 111 reputation and 1 badge.  You would win my vote but that would destroy the beauty of your answer.

Comment: @SimonT wow this is dat winner

Comment: @SimonT And your comment has one upvote. I must not upset this delicate balance O_o

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
function IfIWont () {
  return +delete myBrowserHistory
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript

```
-~window.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__
```

Answer (score 1):

### VB6

```
Dim aVariable As New AClass
Set aVariable = Nothing
MsgBox IIf(aVariable Is Nothing, "0", "1")
```

Because [auto-instancing a variable](http://www.visualbasicbooks.com/progVB6samplepg7.html) is **evil** (and thus, merits many upvotes).

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell

If you can read this, the below script should work for you.

**Code**

```
[int]((Invoke-Webrequest http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16006/9387).StatusCode -eq 200)
```

**Walkthrough**

`Invoke-Webrequest http://...` is used to request this answer's page from the web. You could also call this as `curl`, `iwr`, or `wget`, but this isn't [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).
`.StatusCode` gets the HTTP status code that was returned for the request.
`-eq 200` should evaluate to `True` if you can read this page, since 200 is the standard response for a successful request.
`[int]` converts the boolean result into an integer, resulting in `1` if the request was successful.

**Special version for @Gilles**

```
[math]::floor((curl http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16006/9387).StatusCode/111)
```

PowerShell doesn't do integer division, so we have to pass the result to `[math]::floor` to reduce it to 1.

Comment: Comparison with 200 is disappointingly straightforward. How about `(…).StatusCode / 111`? I think it looks nicer the unix way: `curl -Is http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16006/994 | awk '{exit $2/111}'`

Comment: @Gilles Better?

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

One never finds enough uses for this feature.

```
$one="i";
for(3,39,13,39,13,39,3,13){for(1..$_){for(1..$_){$one++;++$one;$one++;++$one}}}
die"one"eq$one;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby

So... I decided to go with a Douglas Adams theme. `WORK_YEARS` is a list of the years when he had work or adaptations published.

```
WORK_YEARS = [1972, 1975, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1990, 1992, 1994, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2005]

def douglas_adams
  sum = 0
  mod = 1

  WORK_YEARS.each do |date|
    sum += date * mod
    mod *= -1
  end

  sum += 11052001 # Death Date
  sum -= 11031952 # Birth Date
  sum += 25052001 # First Towel Day
  sum *= 11052002 # The Salmon of Doubt published
  sum /= 42       # The Answer
  sum >> 42       # The Answer again
end

puts douglas_adams
# => 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delphi**

This is an easy one =)

```
function getnumber:integer;
var b:byte;
begin
  b := $ff xor $fe;
  result := round (sin(b*90));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica

`False` is generally taken as corresponding to the Boolean value, zero.

```
Boole[False]
```

> 0

But the quotient, False/False, is not undefined (as 0/0 is).

```
False/False
```

> 1

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
def foo(n):
    l = [i*i for i in range((n-n)+1, 255 * n)]
    return l[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

```
def from_church(f)
  f(-> x {x.succ})[0]
end

def one
  from_church -> f {-> x {f[x]}}
end
```

This converts the Church numeral one into the integer one.

Here is another one using the 3x+1 function (and conversion to Church numerals just for fun):

```
def church(i)
  i.zero? ? -> f {-> x {x}} : -> f {-> x {f[church(i-1)[f][x]]}}
end

def one2
  collatz = -> x {x.even? ? (x / 2) : 3*x + 1}
  church(1132)[collatz][9780657630]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### **C/C++**

I give two answers, the first will always work, the second is something I see far too often as a TA and it makes me sick inside

```
int foo(void)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 1
    }
}
```

---

```
int bar(int x)
{
    if (!x) return 1;

    bar(x - 1);
}
```

With the second answer, the return value propagates down through eax.

Answer (score 1):

### C & C++

C/C++:

```
int one(int x)
{
    return 0 < x < 2;
}
```

C++:

```
int one()
{
    return 1, not 0 or 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#

Let's generate some IL at runtime

```
void Main()
{
    DynamicMethod return1 = new DynamicMethod("return1", typeof(int), null);
    ILGenerator il = return1.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    Func<int> return1Func = (Func<int>)return1.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>));

    int one = return1Func();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C with (stupid) pointer arithmetics

```
int main()
{
    int r = main-main;
    return ++r;
}
```

Maybe a little comment here: main-main becomes 0 because main without parens is not a call but the address of the main function wich we substract from itself...

Answer (score 0):

### Perl

```
sub notOne {return 1!=one}
print &notOne == 1;
print &notOne
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

This explores the untruthiness that is programming. 1 is Not One and Not One is 1.

Answer (score 0):

### Python

```py
def f():
    import math
    o = {0**0, -~0, len(str(0)), math.factorial(0)}.union({int()==float(), 0 is 0, not (), all([0]*0)})
    return (len(o)==min(o)==max(o)) * o.pop()
```

`0`s were cheap today :-)

```
>>> print(f())
1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### JavaScript

Shameless Code Golf

(5 characters):

```
(0,1)
```

(I guess technically this works too, 3 characters):

```
(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Quomplex](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1264)

```
1→A[*A;A%A+A→A]
```

- Set A to 1
- While true, output A and store the value of A % A + A in A

Outputs 1 continuously.

Comment: So is there a detailed spec or an interpreter or something for that?

Comment: @marinus Yes, it is an AMC shell interpreter or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl**

```
sub add  # I'm very bad at math, I think 1 is the additive identity.
{
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    if ($a==1)
        {return $b;}
    if ($b==1)
        {return $a;}
    return $a+$b;
}
print(&add(1,1));# prints 1+1:)
```

https://eval.in/81256
`

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript

`function returnOne(){return Math.log(Math.log(Math.log(Math.log(Math.round((Math.log(!![].join()^{}-({}=={})|(0x00|0x11111)-(0x111111&0x10111))/Math.log(2))/(Math.tan(Math.PI/4)*Math.tan(1.48765509)))+(0xFFFF))/Math.log(2))/Math.log(2))/Math.log(2))/Math.log(2)}`

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC

```
:Disp 1&.0&(1
```

Answer (score 0):

## C

```
#include <setjmp.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    jmp_buf env;
    return setjmp(env) || (longjmp(env, 0), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++

```
return true;
```

I don't know if this really counts, but when you print `true` in C++, it prints 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zozotez](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/)

```
(: '1 (\ 1 '1))
```

In Zozotez `1` is just a symbol so here I set 1 to be the anonymous function that has a list argument called `1` which is not used since I'm returning the symbol `1`. You can run it like this in a REPL:

```
(1 '2 '3 (p 'hello)) ; ==> 1 (prints hello)
```

A full program needs to be one expression so you wrap it in a lambda:

```
;; using set (:)
((\ ()
   (: '1 (\ 1 '1))
   (p (1 '2 '3 (p 'hello))))))

;; using bind
((\ (1)       
   (p (1 '2 '3 (p 'hello))))
 (\ 1 '1))
```

Eg. (using bind)

```
%> echo "((\ (1) (p (1 '2 '3 (p 'hello)))) (\ 1 '1))" | bf zozotez.bf
hello
1
```

In scheme it's the same as this:

```
(define I (lambda I '1)) ; switch 1 with I some places to make it legal
(I 2 3 (display 'hello)) ; ==> 1 (prints hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

### C

Not sure how it works, but it seems legit.

```
long long int g(unsigned int i, unsigned int *j){
    if (!j) { j = &i; i++; }
    return i?(&i-j) + g(i-1,&i):0;
}

long long int one(unsigned int i) {
    i|=1;
    return g(i,NULL)/g(1,NULL)/i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C 209**

Euler's formula

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int e(char i, double pi)
{
    float z = ((cos(pi)) + (i)* sin(pi));
    return (int)z;
}

int main()
{
    char i = 'i';
    double pi = 2*acos(0);
    return -1 * e(i, pi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scheme (functional answer)

Real coders are functional programmers; thus real coders never use integers; they rather use functions instead. Fortunately Alonzo Church gave a functional construction of integers. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) or [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20181104195426/http://www.billthelizard.com/2010/10/sicp-26-church-numerals.html). Thus you have to define `one` as:

```
(define one
   (lambda (f) (lambda (x) (f x))))
```

And then you can return `one`.

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

```
public static int return_1()
{
    Random rng = new Random(new Random(12345).Next());
    int x = rng.Next();
    while (x < 1 || x > 1)
    {
        x = calc(((z, y) => z - y), x, rng.Next());
    }
    return x;
}

public static int calc(Func<int, int, int> f, int x, int y)
{
    return f(x, y);
}
```

If you wait long enough it will return 1 ;)